# How can I cause adjacent circles to move in response to an increase in radius of one circle in a cluster of circles?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a layout that contains several circles grouped together on a page. When a circle is clicked its radius will increase. The problem I'm having is that the adjacent circles are not pushed to the side when one of the circles is clicked. The adjacent circles will overlap the circle that was clicked (since it now has a larger radius). It's as if the surrounding circles still remember its original radius, not the new radius. Here is what I have so far:

```
<g id="bubble-nodes">
<rect id="bubble-background"></rect>
<a class="class="bubble-node">
    <circle r="65"></circle>
</a>
....
</g>

var circle = d3
.selectAll('circle')
.on('click', function (d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("r", 85);
});
```

How can I force the adjacent circles to get push out so they are now touching the new perimeter of the larger circle and not the older perimeter?

Comment: You would need to rerun your layout algorithm with the changed radius.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm still a newb to d3.js.

Comment: Whatever you did to compute the positions of the circles to start with you need to do again.